# Throttle calling a function with ajax call using lodash

Tags: jquery, lodash

I am trying to throttle an ajax call that is wrapped in a function, but it does not seem to do anything, It just seems to carry on when the breakpoint hits the throttle line and does not enter the getPrice method

```
_.throttle(getPrice, 1000);

var getPrice= function getPrice() {
  $.ajax({
    // call api
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`throttle()` returns a *new* function which has the delay applied to it. It's that new function which you need to call, not the original. Try this:

```
var originalGetPrice = function() {
  $.ajax({
    // call api
  });
};

var getPrice = _.throttle(originalGetPrice, 1000);
```

Note you can use `getPrice()` as normal in your logic and it will have the 1000ms delay applied to it.

Comment: I want to ensure that the api does not get called more than once a second. Is throttle the correct method for that? Its still calling it multiple times when I was expecting only one call